# I want to have ASCII output just with char array in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, char, ascii

Hey guys I nee your help;

```
char[] cha = new char[] 
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
```

I made this array.

but

```
foreach (char a in cha)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```

when I use this code the output is just a, b, c, d....z

But when I use this code

```
foreach (char a in cha)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + g);
        }
```

the output is ASCII number.
I want to have ASCII output without g
what do I have to do?

Thank you.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((int)a);`

Comment: well, a `char` is nothing but a **number**. Doing `+` will thus add those numbers,.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Oh..I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var cha = new[] {'a'};
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cha);
```

Also you can use `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32('a')
```

or just explicitly cast to `int`:

```
int x = (int)'a';
```

Comment: I like that Cover.ToInt32.
I ll try your answer now thank you!